# How to use variables of other buttons in java gui

Tags: java, javascript

i want to use variable `Drink_quan`

```
private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

  tab = jTextField4.getText();
  int Drink_quan = Integer.parseInt(tab);

}
```

in

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Drink_quan);  

}
```

but it doesn't show any message

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a class variable. Then you set it's value in the `jTextField4ActionPerformed` and later you can use it in `jButton1ActionPerformed`. As it is, you can't use it because `Drink_quan`   is a local variable in the method `jTextField4ActionPerformed`.

Comment: i did that but it's private is that be a problem

Answer (score 2):

the variable `Drink_quan` is only defined within the scope of the first function, therefore when the function exists - this variable dies.

declare it outside of the function to use it in both of them ( and in any other functions in your class):

```
int Drink_quan;

private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    tab = jTextField4.getText();
    rink_quan = Integer.parseInt(tab);
} 

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,Drink_quan);  
}
```